# UITableView has different rows in different orientation  and how to the make visible cell display the same stuff after rotate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have photo app like photoAlbum. I display the photo thumbnails in UITableView.Eech UITableViewCell has four thumbnails  in portrait mode and six thumbnails in landscape mode.So,there are different rows in different orientation.If I rotate to other orientation, I  reload data in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:` method .After rotate ,the visible row in UITableView always the same like the previous orientation,so the visible thumbnails are different from the previous orientation.My problem is how to make the UITableView display the same visible thumbnails in the UITableViewCell after rotate like the iPhone photoAlbum.I need the UITableView scroll to the correct row in different orientation,so that the thumbnails in different orientation are the same.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Find out what rows are visible before the rotation using

`NSArray *paths = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];`

After the rotation, find the first row and scroll to it using

```
NSIndexPath *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:path atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Comment: NO,it does not work.I thought I didn't make my problem clear.If the tableview has the same number of rows in portrait mode and landscape mode ,your answer is right ,but my tableView has different number of rows in different orientation.

Comment: Ok, I'll leave this answer as wrong so more people don't get confused.